# jquery ui dialog in asp.net mvc3 doesn't open on second time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-dialog

when i click the New Trade button in the form it opens jquery ui dialog. but, i have link button in the gridview when i click the link button it should open jquery ui dialog, it opens jquery ui dialog before clicking the new trade button. but, after clicking the new trade button, if i click link button in the gridview it invoke "ViewTradeDialog(id)" function, the dialog doesn't open, it shows error message "$vwdia.html(data).dialog is not a function". my code follows:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("NewTrade", "Trade", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "searchForm" }))
{

    <div id="searchbtn">
        <input id="btn_newtrade" type="submit" value="New Trade" />
    </div>


}


jquery code

  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {






     var $loading = $('<img src="../../loading.gif" alt="loading">');



     var $dialog = $('<div></div>').append($loading);


     $('#searchForm').submit(function (e) {

         var url = this.action;

         $.ajax({
            autoOpen: false,
             url: url,
             success: function (data) {
                 $dialog.html(data).dialog({
                     zIndex:1,
                     width: 1400,
                     height: 600,
                     resizable: false,
                     title: 'New Trade Details',
                     modal: true,
                     buttons: {
                         "close": function () {
                             $dialog.dialog('close');
                         },

                         "Add Trade": function () {
                             $dialog.dialog('close');
                             $.ajax({
                                 type: 'POST',
                                 url: url

                             });
                         }
                     }
                 });
             }
         });
         return false;

     });



 });



 function ViewTradeDialog(id) {



     alert(id);

     var $vwdia = $('<div></div>');

     var url = '/Trade/ViewTrades?tradeid=' + id;


     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         success: function (data) {
             $vwdia.html(data).dialog({

                 width: 600,
                 height: 600,
                 resizable: false,
                 title: 'View Trade Details',
                 modal: false,
                 buttons: {
                     "close": function () {
                         $vwdia.dialog('close');
                     }
                 }
             });
         }
     });



     return false;


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overwriting the dialog plugin each time you click new trade, since it is applied to the same element:

```
$dialog.html(data).dialog(...
```

It is possible that by replacing the html of the dialog and reapplying the plugin that it is breaking. Are you seeing any other errors in the JS console?

Comment: I don't have time to fix it to you but I would say that I prefer to separate my dialogs out and fix them on the page instead of creating dynamically as you are. I would have my dialog divs live on the page and just wire them up once at document.ready and then open and close them when required. Just doing that might fix your problem.